# Write Java String to file with special encoding

Tags: java, delphi, file-io, encoding

I have got the Java String `ôð¤ Ø$î1<¨ V¸dPžÐ ÀH@ˆàÀà¼€@`~€4` which I would like to write to a file with ANSI encoding.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output),"windows-1252"));
    try {   
        out.append(str);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```

Debugger says that `str` contains `ôð¤ Ø$î1<¨ V¸dPÐ ÀH@àÀà¼@`~4. As soon as I write it to the output file, the file only contains `?ÒÜ@4`. So whats wrong with my method writing to the File?

Sorry for this weird strings - I am trying to rewrite a delphi 7 function in java. These strings are the only samples I have got.

Comment: What are you using to read the output file? Unless that's *also* using Windows-1252, you'll get bad results. There's also the possibility that not all of those values are even *in* Windows-1252.

Comment: Are you sure you are viewing the file correctly? What is the length of the file? Is it ~5 or ~32 in length? Non-supported character should turn into `?` as the first one did, not disappear.

Comment: @Jan: Nope, no exception at all.

Comment: @Jon I am using Notepad++ which shows ANSI as encoding of both files. The Filesize of the original file (written by delphi) is 35 - same as the String. Length of my file is 5.

Comment: If you are interpretting the file with a different encoding than was used to write the file, you _will_ get a different text ... but a file size of 5 was unexpected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I run

```
String text = "ôð¤ Ø$î1<¨ V¸dPžÐ ÀH@ˆàÀà¼€@`~€4";
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test.txt"), "windows-1252");
writer.append(text);
writer.close();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.txt"), "windows-1252"));
String line = br.readLine();
br.close();
System.out.println(line.length() + ": '" + line + "' matches " + line.equals(text));
```

it prints

```
32: 'ôð¤ Ø$î1<¨ V¸dPžÐ ÀH@ˆàÀà¼€@`~€4' matches true
```

so no characters are lost in translation.

---

If I change the encoding to "US-ASCII" I get the following output

```
32: '??? ?$?1<? V?dP?? ?H@??????@`~?4' matches false
```

Comment: If I do that everything is fine. Seems like there is a difference between hardcoding the string, and calculating it.

Comment: That's the point. Did set the debugger encoding to ANSI. The string differed from the one posted. So Peter was right.

Comment: @k_wave: It wouldn't be the debugger - it would be the compiler.

Comment: My IDE uses UTF-8 file format, but even if it was the "wrong" encoding the string wouldn't be truncated, it would have many `?` in it.